# Image fill fixed height div

Tags: html, css, height

I'm stuck on a `css`problem.

I have a div with fixed height, `400px` and inside that div there is some variable text. And an image, I need the image to fill the space of the div. The text will change so the space always is different and all must be inside the height bounds.

Comment: Please add code samples of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, I will add some code, but I can tell you I have player with heights values and displays. I tried with `display: table` but when content is longer than `400px` the container expands if it's not `display: block`

Comment: I Made a Code for you which is easiest way to solve your problem Check this link. Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Arsh_kalsi01/ckryvuzm/2/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using `display: flex` and setting image on background of a div.

You can see code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ckryvuzm/

I tried using `display: table` but the fixed height of `400px` grows when content changes.

Answer (score 0):

Define the Width of the div to 100% that contains the height of 400px and display: flex and flex-direction: column.

Inside it make Image div to the flex-grow: 1.

And put all of your content inside one div, and make overflow: auto, as there will be less content it will not have scroll and if the content grows in size the content will get a scroll-bar.

Here made a fiddle which I think exactly solve your Issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ABhimsaria/vj7bgzpb/2/

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
```

}